# RawSourceWaveStream volume control and playback time estimation with Naudio

Tags: audio, volume, naudio

I'm using Naudio to play audio samples from memory.

```
        private RawSourceWaveStream waveStream;
        private MemoryStream ms;
        private int sampleRate = 48000;
        private IWavePlayer wavePlayer;

        //generate sine wave signal
        short[] buffer = new short[(int)Math.Round(sampleRate * 10.00)];
        double amplitude = 0.25 * short.MaxValue;
        double frequency = 1000;
        for (int n = 0; n < buffer.Length; n++)
        {
            buffer[n] = (short)(amplitude * Math.Sin((2 * Math.PI * n * frequency) / sampleRate));
        }
        byte[] byteBuffer = new byte[buffer.Length * sizeof(short)];
        Buffer.BlockCopy(buffer, 0, byteBuffer, 0, byteBuffer.Length);

        //create audio player to play samples from memory
        ms = new MemoryStream(byteBuffer);
        waveStream = new RawSourceWaveStream(ms, new WaveFormat(sampleRate, 16, 1));
        //wavePlayer = new WaveOutEvent();
        wavePlayer = new DirectSoundOut();

        wavePlayer.Init(waveStream);
        wavePlayer.PlaybackStopped += wavePlayer_PlaybackStopped;
```

I want to control the Volume of `RawSourceWaveStream` for each stream separately.
(I will play multiple streams).

1) It's enough to use `wavePlayer.Volume = volumeSlider1.Volume;`? It is deprecated.

2) I see that `AudioFileReader` make use of `SampleChannel` for Volume control. If i rewrite Read method for `RawSourceWaveStream` and add Volume Property should this be a good solution?

3) I want playback time estimation as best as possible (at millisecond level). I saw that the time resolution of `WaveOutEvent` is about hundred of milliseconds. The time resolution of `DirectSoundOut` is better, but still not enough.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) yes you can use `WaveOut.Volume`. Another option is to use something like `VolumeSampleProvider` to do the volume in our signal chain rather than on the device

2) No need to rewrite it - call the `.ToSampleProvider()` extension method and then pass it through a `VolumeSampleProvider`

3) The `Position` on your RawSourceStream shows you how far you have read into the file, but not accurately where playback is because some of the audio may still be buffered ready to play. Look at `GetPosition()` on `WaveOut` which returns the number of bytes played so far, and is the most accurate option available.

Comment: The problem with `code`GetPosition() from `code`WaveOut is that reports total bytes played. If you Pause the play and then seek and resume, the play time will not be reported correctly.

Comment: Yes, it's calling through to an underlying waveOut API that does exactly that.